# WPF MVVM load View and ViewModel from external assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

so I have inherited the development of a WPF application that uses Caliburn.Micro.  I have been tasked to extend the application and include some AddIn functionality, I have coded the core logic for the AddIn feature which all works pretty well until I run the application and the shell view informs me that it "Cannot find view for TestViewModel"

Here is my Configure method in the bootstrapper

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    this._log.Debug("-->AppBootstrapper.Configure[ENTER]");
    try
    {
        SplashScreenForm.SplashScreen.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                (Action)(() => SplashScreenForm.SplashScreen.Message = "Initializing Container..."));

        this._container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(new DirectoryCatalog(".", "*")));
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        SplashScreenForm.SplashScreen.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                (Action)(() => SplashScreenForm.SplashScreen.Message = "Initializing Dependencies..."));
        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());

        batch.AddExportedValue(this._container);
        this._container.Compose(batch);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this._log.ErrorFormat("-->AppBootstrapper.Configure - {0}\n{1}", ex.Message, ex);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }

    this._log.Debug("-->AppBootstrapper.Configure[EXIT]");
}
```

I then have two assemblies, AppMain which contains the main application logic (this has a ViewModels and Views folders and these all load fine), I also have an AppAddinTest assembly which contains a test addin, this also contains a ViewModels and Views folder.

My TestViewModel code is:

```
[Export(typeof(TestViewModel))]
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel, ITestViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TestViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this._eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this._windowManager = windowManager;
    }
}
```

And the TestView.xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Cleo.Windows.Ui.Views.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="This is a test view from a different assembly!!"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Could anyone shed any light on what I have done wrong please and also why the application is unable to find the view?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you haven't added the assembly on the stage of bootstrapping where your ViewModel resides.
Override `SelectAssemblies()` in the bootstrapper:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies() {
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly> {
            //AddTheAssemblyWhereViewModelsReside
        };
        return assemblies;
    }
```